# How should I customize the Button color?

Tags: material-ui

As stated in the doc, the color property accepts enums of "default", "inherit", "primary", "secondary". I want an arbitrary color other than "primary" and "secondary". A possible solution is by utilizing the "Overriding with classes" feature where I can specify the root background, and it works.

```js
const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(44, 152, 240)",
  }
};

function FloatingActionButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Button
      variant="fab"
      classes={{ root: classes.root }}
    >
      <Icon style={{ fontSize: 34 }}>play_arrow</Icon>
    </Button>
  );
}
```

However, when the mouse hangs over the button, the background restores to the default light grey. This behavior is different when I specify the color property to "primary", in which case the background dims a bit when the mouse hangs over.
How should I specify the customized color correctly?

Comment: This seems to be an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49085512/4982809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hover selector

```js
const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(44, 152, 240)",
    '&:hover':{
      backgroundColor:"rgba(44, 152, 240)",
    },
  }
};
```

Have a look at [Customized Buttons](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#customized-buttons) for more details.

Comment: Nice. Another way to go about it is to set up a standalone theme for this particular button and use "primary" as color. But it's a bit overkill.