# How to Change Color of Button Material UI Tag on React js after Clicked?

Tags: reactjs, web, material-design

i have created w multi step register form and to do the validation it gives error and want to do the validation with this format export const CreateAccount extends Component like this i wan

Comment: check here you will find several answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486565/material-ui-next-customize-button-colors

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current color of the button in the state and just switch its value when the button is clicked. Something like this:

```
const DynamicButton = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("primary")

  const switchColor = () => {
    if (color === "primary") setColor("secondary")
    else setColor("primary")
  }

  return (
    <Button
      color={color}
      onClick={switchColor}
      variant="contained"
    >
      Click me to change my color!
    </Button>
  )
}
```

This is using React hooks. But if you are using React class components the equivalent code would be like this:

```
class DynamicButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      color: "primary"
    }
  }

  switchColor = () => {
    if (this.state.color === "primary") this.setState({ color: "secondary" })
    else this.setState({ color: "primary" })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        color={this.state.color}
        onClick={this.switchColor}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Click me to change my color!
      </Button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: const DynamicButton = () => { for what is or its the class cause i am a bit confussed

Comment: Also i implemented to my code when refresh to web browser it show something like : TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'formData' as it is undefined. casue i have used for modal pop up

Comment: The class is just in case you are using React class components instead of React hooks. If you are using hooks just ignore that class code

Comment: Maybe if you shared some of your code I would help you better

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io8al.png)
how to do that color and setcolor to get another color for example setColor ("orange") with material ui of course when i do that to setcolor it changes nothing